# Docker Build Requires exactly 1 argument ubuntu

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I keep getting this error: docker build requires exactly one argument after typing:

docker build -t megahit

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)? You are missing the last required argument: `docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -`

Answer (score 1):

`docker build` needs an argument of the path to build from. If you want to build the current directory (i.e., your dockerfile is located in the current directory), that would be `.`:

```
docker build -t megahit .
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that and then I get an error saying "cannot connect to Docker Daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running. So I use sudo service docker start and it says it's running but when I check the status it says it's not running

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future looking at this comment this
"cannot connect to Docker Daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running"
it means probably docker isn't installed in your system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).